# Modify CSV field on import to mysql

Tags: mysql, string, datetime, csv, import

I'm trying to import a CSV file to a mysql database.

The CSV file contains (amongst other things) dates in the following format:

```
"2010-04-31 17:43:12"
```

My first approach was to use the following .sql script:

```
USE test;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.cvs'
replace INTO TABLE test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(...,mydate,...);
```

which doesn't work because the double quotes make the field "2010-04-31 17:43:12" a string.
So i figured out i can convert it to DATETIME format using

```
select STR_TO_DATE("2010-04-31 17:43:12",'(%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%S)') AS NewDateTime
```

That query works fine on it's own but I was wondering if there's a way of converting the string on the fly while importing. Something amongst the following:

```
...
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(...,STR_TO_DATE(mydate,'(%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%S)') AS NewDateTime,...);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the column list, and then use the SET command to apply the STR_TO_DATE:

```
(@date,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,)
SET mydate = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%S')
```

Related:

- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,136269,136269#msg-136269

Comment: @kirbuchi: You're welcome.  I'm surprised it doesn't come up more often