# Parsing Dates for from CSV for SQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, parsing, datetime

I am using the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE function to pull log data from a csv into a mysql DB so I can use it in Rails.

Using the answer to this question:
[Modify CSV field on import to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939295/modify-csv-field-on-import-to-mysql)

The only issue I have is how to parse my date time field.

Thu Mar 01 11:49:16 +0000 2012

STR_TO_DATE(@csvdate, '??????????')

Comment: Do you want to insert datetime with timezone?

Comment: I removed the +0000 manually and can parse it effectively now, but if you could show me how to parse datetime from above it would save me time in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use STR_TO_DATE function. For example -

```
SET @date = 'Thu Mar 01 11:49:16 2012';
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%a %b %d %H:%i:%S %Y');
```

[STR_TO_DATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: this is what I am using,

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Thu Mar 01 10:22:17 2012', '%a %b %e %T %Y') AS date;

it will do for now and I'll review when I have more time, thanks for your help